# How to measure the temperature of an object under white light?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

How do you measure the temperature of an object which is under white light (or light with a specific wavelength)?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what physics you are having trouble with. Please clarify the question.

Comment: What does "under the white light" mean? The object is exposed to a constant beam of light? Assuming you're asking for the temperature when the system is in thermal equilibrium the solution also depends very much on the specifics of the object. If it is a "black body", the solution to your problem is given by the Stefan-Boltzmann law.

Comment: 1) I don't think it would be a homework, thus I removed this tag 2) I changed the "calculation" to "measurement", because the OP thinks clearly to the second.

Answer (score 0):

The reflected light has no direct coincidence with the temperature of the object.

What you can see from the object under white light, is the sum of two light spectrum:

1. *reflected* light, i.e. what the object reflects back from the light what is gets. Its spectrum can be calculated by multiplying the albedo of the object with the spectrum of the incoming light.
2. temperature radiation. Most cases it nears the black body spectrum with some differences. Its spectrum can be calculated by the [Stefan-Boltzman law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

Knowing (1), it is relatively easy to calculate (2), and thus the temperature of the object from them.

Note, in white light and in room temperature, the two spectrums are essentially disjunct: white light has a near-equal energy distribution between 360 - 720 nm, objects would require many thousands ${{}^\circ}\mathrm{K}$ to radiate mainly in this wavelength interval.